# Search for a symbol in a multi-package stack project

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Is there any tool that can be used to search for the location in which a symbol (e.g. function) is defined within a Haskell project built with stack, which contains multiple packages?

I'm not looking for any IDE integration, anything better than:

```bsh
egrep --color -R --include="*.hs"  "someSymbol" sys/*/src
```

will do.

If, additionally, this tool can provide other information such as uses of a symbol, that'd be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be

```bsh
ag --haskell "someSymbol" sys/*/src
```

Answer (score 2):

[Hoogle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hoogle) can be locally installed and its database populated with all of the information from the packages in your project.

Additionally, [haddock](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haddock) can generate documentation, and part of the documentation it generates is an index of all symbols, in alphabetical order, together with information about which module(s) define that symbol. It also has generally good tool support, so I expect a single `stack` command would be able to build all the haddocks for your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for IDE-like experience, check out [Haskell IDE engine](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-ide-engine) that integrates with editors which [support Language Server Protocol](http://langserver.org/#implementations-client).